# Is posible update my db without drop and create?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF with CodeFirst if I make any changes in the classes, the change is reflected in the db, the problem is that it drop the db and losses the values in the tables,  with Nhibernate i could change mapping and updating the db without a drop, this can be done with EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use EntityFramework Migrations. Here are a couple links to get you started:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx